# Set Excel Range Formatting With Array

Tags: excel, vba

I have, in the past, used a variant array to populate a range of multiple Excel cells.

I'm wondering, is there a way to do the same thing with cell formatting?  I'd rather not go cell by cell, and it'd be nice to minimize the number of calls to get an Excel range...

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can apply formatting to a multi-cell Range and not have to do it cell-by-cell, but I don't do a ton of formatting. Probably someone who does will give a real answer...

Comment: Wow, I totally misunderstood the question. Lance Roberts's answer looks correct to me, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@ExcelHero has pointed out to me how to get this done, so here's how.

If your range is horizontal, then just feed it an array built of Format strings:

```
[a1:c1].NumberFormat = Array("hh:mm", "General", "$#,##0.00")
```

If your range is vertical, then transpose that array, since Excel considers Arrays to be horizontal:

```
[a1:a3].NumberFormat = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Array("hh:mm", "General", "$#,##0.00"))
```

**Old Answer:**

No, you can't do each cell separately, though you can bulk assign one format to an entire range.

The property of a Range to assign to is `.NumberFormat`.  If you create a variant array of strings to assign as a format, then assign it to the range, only the first element gets applied (and it gets applied to all cells of the range).

So the best you can do is loop:

```
Dim r As Range
Dim v(1 To 3) As Variant
Dim i As Integer

Set r = Range("A1:A3")
v(1) = "hh:mm:ss"
v(2) = "General"
v(3) = "$#,##0.00_);[Red]($#,##0.00)"

For i = 1 to 3
  r(i).NumberFormat = v(i)
Next i
```

Comment: Thanks - I figured the best I could do was loop. It'd be really nice if MS set up the formats like they do the cell values in terms of arrays...

Comment: This is not true! Array assignment for NumberFormats does work.  [a1:c:10].NumberFormat = Array(a, b, c) where a, b, and c are NF strings. This works just fine.

Comment: @ExcelHero, Just tested with VBA code using `[a1:a3].NumberFormat = Array("hh:mm:ss", "General", "$#,##0.00_);[Red]($#,##0.00)")`. Only the first cell was formatted as per the array.

Comment: @LanceRoberts That's becuase Excel always treats VBA's 1D arrays as horizontal vectors. This behavior is universal and has nothing to do with applying the NumberFormats. Try [a1:C3].NumberFormat =... and you'll see what I mean. Or setup a 2D array.

Comment: @ExcelHero, you keep giving me references that reference more than 3 cells, so I"m confused. Do you mean in the last example [a1:c1]?

Answer (score 4):

I mostly do what Lance suggests.  However, there are some cases where I will make a separate, hidden worksheet with the formats I want set up.  Then I'll

```
wshHidden.Range("A1:D100").Copy
wshReport.Range("A1:D100").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
```

That takes care of it in one fell swoop.  But you do have the overhead of the hidden sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully I can safely presume you are doing this for performance reasons.  As answered above, its not really possible the same way you can do with cell contents.

However, if the formatting of cells is often the same as last time you formatted it, it is much faster to first check if the format needs to change, and only then change it.

Here is a function that can do it.  In tests (Excel 2003), this runs 8x-10x faster than always setting the format, and that is with screen updating turned off.

```
Sub SetProperty(ByRef obj As Object, propname, newvalue)
    If CallByName(obj, propname, VbGet) <> newvalue Then
        Call CallByName(obj, propname, VbLet, newvalue)
    End If
End Sub
```

Call it like this:

```
Call SetProperty(Cells(1,1).Font, "ColorIndex", 27) 
Call SetProperty(Cells(1,1).Borders, "Weight", xlMedium)
etc
```