# VBA Table ClearFormat except NumberFormat

Tags: excel, vba

I am currently creating a table in VBA and setting TableStyle, which is working well. However, sometimes cells in the table have cell or column formatting before the table is created, messing up the style of the table. When I create the table I want to first clear formatting EXCEPT the NumberFormat, which I want to maintain.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35924246/7619676) answer to capture NumberFormat and then reapply to a range after using ClearFormats, but it doesn't seem to be working in my case. My code:

```
Sub CreateTable(ws As Worksheet, rng As Range, tblname As String)
    On Error Resume Next
        ws.ListObjects(tblname).Unlist
    On Error GoTo 0

    Dim tbl As ListObject
    Set tbl = ws.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, rng, , xlYes)
    Dim numfmt
    numfmt = tbl.Range.NumberFormat
    tbl.Range.ClearFormats  'works
    tbl.Range.NumberFormat = numfmt  ' doesn't work
    'tbl.Range.NumberFormat = "0.00%"  'works
    'Range("AE8:AE10").NumberFormat = "0.00%"  ' works
    tbl.TableStyle = "TableStyleMedium15"
    tbl.Name = tblname

End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Worksheets("sheetname")

    ' Inject Main Table
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = ws.Range(ws.Range("A7"), ws.Range("A7").SpecialCells(xlLastCell))
    Dim tblname As String
    tblname = "MyTable"
    Call CreateTable(ws, rng, tblname)
    ...
End Sub
```

How can I maintain my cell/column number formats without allowing other formats that would conflict with my table?

---

## Update #1

Based on the comments I tried the following, but my syntax clearly isn't quite right, and the looping is also incredibly slow.

```
Dim numfmt
numfmt = tbl.Range.NumberFormat
tbl.Range.ClearFormats
For Each cell In tbl.Range
     cell.NumberFormat = numfmt
Next cell
```

I also found this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3857225/7619676 which looks like it's possible to set NumberFormat from an array, but struggling with the syntax for a 2d range with this solution as well.

Comment: Do you have a preferred style?  e.g., no fill, specific font, specific font size?  you can apply those, rather than clearing format, which will allow numberformat to remain

Comment: I want no other cell formatting except numberformat, so that there's nothing that can conflict with the table formatting. The initial issue that led me down this path was that unlisting the table with `ws.ListObjects(tblname).Unlist` leaves the style of the table as formatting, and then when I recreate the table, there's cell formatting I don't want. In this case I think finding a way to clear the formatting that tablestyle leaves behind when a table is converted to a range would also cover me.

Comment: You will need to iterate the cells in the table and do it one by one. `numfmt = tbl.Range.NumberFormat` returns an array of numberformats.  You cannot set an array of types.

Comment: Thanks. Are you able to post an example of how to loop through and set for a 2d range like this and then set the numberformat back on the object? Having trouble with the syntax

Comment: Can you post some sample data to understand better the issue? Is the same number format for every table? Does it apply to all cells?

Comment: I won’t be able to post sample data until tomorrow, but each column has a consistent number format and there are ~70 columns. There’s only a few different formats used across all the columns.